# Assumption in PDE theory

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I have an exercise in PDE theory.
Let $w \in C^2(U)\cap C(\overline{U})$ where $U$ is open, bounded and connected and $c \in C(\overline{U},\mathbb{R})$ with $c(x) \le 0$ everywhere. Moreover, $u\rvert_{\partial U}=0$ and $u$ solves 
$$\Delta u(x) =-c(x)u(x)$$
 Then, I am supposed to show that $u(x)=0$ for all $x \in \overline{U}.$

Now, I have figured out a proof, but I don't need the connectedness. This makes me suspicious, so please could anybody check my proof:

Let $G:=\{x \in U; u(x) > 0\}.$ Then we have $\Delta u(x) =-c(x)u(x) \ge 0$ on $G.$ Thus, $u$ is subharmonic on $G$ and $G$ is open (as the preimage of an open interval) and bounded as $U$ is bounded. Thus, we can apply the maximum principle for subharmonic functions and get

$$\max_{\overline{G}} u =  \max_{\partial G}u.$$

We show that $u$ is zero on $\partial G.$

If $x \in \partial G \cap \partial U$ then $u$ is zero by assumption in the theorem.

If $x \in \partial G \backslash \partial U$ then $\,x \in \operatorname{int}\left(U\right).\,$ Thus, we have, as $\,x \notin G$ that $u(x) \le 0.\,$ But by continuity we must have $u(x)=0.$

Thus, $u$ is zero on $\partial G.$

Hence, we get that $u$ must be zero in $\overline{G}.$

Now, we can apply the same argument to $-u$ in order to see that $u$ is actually zero everywhere.

Clearly, I did not mention the connectedness of $U$ anywhere and thus, I guess there is something wrong. What do you think?

Comment: Er....I don't think your problem is correctly specified at the moment, because your hypotheses don't say anything about the Laplacian of anything.

Comment: What's the equation that is solved by $u$?

Comment: @Ian yes, sorry.

Comment: @bartgol yes, I added it.

Comment: Shouldn't $G$ be connected for the maximum principle?

Comment: @Hetebrij I think no connectedness is needed in the case of the WEAK maximum principle that is used here. The one that needs the connectedness goes something like: If $u$ attains its maximum inside, then $u$ is constant everywhere.

Comment: If $U$ is not connected, you can consider each connected component separately. If connectedness is important, it still follows that $u\equiv 0$ on each component. So indeed, the connectedness is not essential.

Comment: @DanielFischer  thank you. Do you think my proof is correct, too?

Comment: Modulo the possible problem of invoking the maximum principle. If the maximum principle was only proven for connected open sets, you need to either deduce the principle for disconnected open sets from it, or apply it to each connected component of $G$ (essentially it's the same thing) to have a complete proof.

Comment: @Surfaceint You're correct. And if someone stumbling upon this question needs a reference in the future: Evans, Partial Differential Equations, Section 6.4.1, Theorem 1.